# How to make item visible and invisible by clicking same line?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have one Linearlayout - totalincome and another TableLayout normalincometable, which should appear just below the totalincome. normalincometable will be invisible when the program runs. When the user clicks on "totalincome" the table should display. If the user clicks on "totalincome again", the table should disappear. I have tried this code, but It didnt work.

```
totalincome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        int x =0;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (x==0)
        {
            normalincometable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            x=1;
        }
        else 
        {
            normalincometable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            x=0;
        }
    });
}
```

From this code, I can make the table visible in first click but It doesnt disappear in next click. Are there any options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared **int x =0;** inside onClick method. So, when ever onClick is called, it assigns 0 to "x". Declare it outside at class scope.

Comment: Got it. It was stupid mistake. I will accept your answer as correct after 7 minutes, when the system allows me. This and the next answer are clear enough to understand it.

Comment: Happy to help. We all make mistakes :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  if(normalincometable.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    normalincometable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  } else {
    normalincometable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are changing visibility of button here.correct your code.

Comment: It makes the the line, where you want to click invisible. On the side, I dont think,assigning a number would be more efficient than checking the view visibility everytime. Not the answer, I was looking.

Answer (score 1):

because you have define x in the button click code so whenever button click it set to 0. define x outside the button click scope.

Answer (score 1):

try this way:put x variable outside the button `onclick()` or defined x globally

```
int x =0;
totalincome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (x==0)
        {
        normalincometable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        x=1;
        }
        else 
        {
            normalincometable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                x=0;
                        }


});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
   int x =0;    
    totalincome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (x==0)
                        {
                        normalincometable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        x=1;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            normalincometable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                x=0;
                                        }


                });

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Boolean isFirstTimeClicked=true;
totalincome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isFirstTimeClicked)
            {
            normalincometable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else 
            {
                normalincometable.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }
isFirstTimeClicked=!isFirstTimeClicked;

    });

}
```

and in your code you  have declared int x =0; inside onClick method. So, when ever onClick is called, it assigns 0 to "x". Declare it outside at class scope.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Method is

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE == button.getVisibility() ? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
```